# Element wise creation of matrix

Tags: matlab

How can we create element wise matrix from 4 matrices without using loops. For ex.we have

> A=[a1 a2;a3 a4] B=[b1 b2;b3 b4] C=[c1 c2;c3 c4] D=[d1 d2;d3 d4]

We need to create a cell array such that each array location contains values such as

> [a1 b1;c1 d1]    %Matrix at First location
>
> [a2 b2;c2 d2]  %Matrix at Second location

and so on so that all the elements are covered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version:

```
newMatrix= permute(reshape([A(:),B(:),C(:),D(:)]',2,2,4),[2,1,3]);
```

The matrices that you need are in newMatrix(:,:,idx)

Lets break it down:

```
temp1 = [A(:),B(:),C(:),D(:)]';
```

`temp1` is a new matrix that contains all of the other matrices values in every row and the values you need for the new matrices (that you wanted to create) in every column.

```
temp2 = reshape([A(:),B(:),C(:),D(:)]',2,2,4);
```

`temp2` takes `temp1` and permutates it. Basically it changes the matrix dimensions from a 4X4 to 2X2X4. if you look at each "layer" (along the 3rd dimension) of this 3D matrix i.e. every 2X2 it contains the information you wanted only transposed. So all thats left to do is transpose it , here `'` doesnt work since its a 3D matrix so we use

```
newMatrix = permute(temp2,[2,1,3]);
```

This means that the third dimensions stais the same but you switch between dimensions 1,2.

Comment: Very well explained! Thanks.